# Binary quadratic forms

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Is it known exactly for which integers $a,b,c$ the equation $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=0$ has a nontrivial solution? If not, what is known about this problem in general? (I am asking about the specific problem of "for which integers $a,b,c$ does $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=0$ have a nontrivial solution in integers $x$ and $y$?)

Thanks

Comment: if it has a solution with integers and $y \neq 0,$ you can divide through by $y^2,$ then define rational $r=x/y$ to get $a r^2 + b r + c = 0.$ When does this have rational roots $r?$

Comment: @WillJagy: Using the rational root theorem we see that it has rational roots when $x$ divides $c$ and $y$ divides $a$. Sorry, but I don't see how this relates to the problem.

Comment: @WillJagy: Sorry, it has rational roots when $b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: @WillJagy: Yes, I've got it. Thanks a lot! So is it true that if $b^2-4ac$ isn't a perfect square, then it has no solutions?